# How to select a javascript element with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a snippet from the HTML page. I want to know how I can use selenium to click on this javascript. The actual link is https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/countdown-to-fomc.html

```
<a id="ctl00_MainContent_ucViewControl_IntegratedFedWatchTool_lbPTree" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$ucViewControl_IntegratedFedWatchTool$lbPTree','')">Probabilities</a>
```

I am getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[id='ctl00_MainContent_ucViewControl_IntegratedFedWatchTool_lbPTree']"}
```

I have tried the below but no luck!

```
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Probabilities']")[0]

link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a*='Probabilities'")
link.click()
```

I want to have selenium to be able to click on this button using Python.

Comment: `a[title='Probabilities']` would match an *attribute*, `<a title="..." ...>...</>`. I'd recommend reading up on what options you have with CSS (and probably XPath) selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That button is in an iframe, you would need to change the focus of webdriver to frame, for that you can use this code

**Code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/countdown-to-fomc.html")

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id^='cmeIframe-']")))

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Probabilities'))).click()
```

You need to import these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Let me know if you have any more concerns.

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[id*='_MainContent_ucViewControl_IntegratedFedWatchTool_']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Probabilities"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@id, '_MainContent_ucViewControl_IntegratedFedWatchTool_') and text()='Probabilities']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

since your a element has `id` attribute you can use that to find it and click on it

```
 driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_ucViewControl_IntegratedFedWatchTool_lbPTree')
```